# How do you read an expression such as e^{-rt}

Tags: exponential-function, pronunciation

I heard people say that
`the exponential to the power of R times T`

> e^{rt}

Is it normal?

What about other similar things?

> e^{-rt}

Is it read

`the exponential to the` **negative** `power of R times T`

or

`the exponential to the power of` **negative** `R times T`

or

`the exponential to the` **negative** `exponent of R times T`

What do you think about?

Comment: sometimes I say, "e to the (negative) r t"

Comment: For the other situation, do you say "e to the negative r t"? thx

Comment: How about "the exponential to the negative r t"?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter but I say $e^M$ as "e to the M" whatever M is, so I'd so $e^{-rt}$ as "eee to the negative arrh tee"  ... anyway "the exponential to the negative exponent of R times T" doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: Does "the exponential to the power of negative rt" sound more clear as well as avoid confusion?

Comment: No, it is not clear. "The exponential" isn't a thing. "Exponential" is an adjective; you need a noun. There are exponential _distributions_. There is an exponential _function_, but the function is not being raised to a power.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. So as others suggest "e to the power of negative rt". Are you saying that "the exponential constsant e to the power of negative rt"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `e^rt` is sloppy. Either write it as $e^{rt}$ or `e^{rt}` so that you won't confuse it with $e^r\cdot t$. (The expression $\exp(rt)$ is also used very often.)

As long as the context is clear, "$e$ to the power of $rt$" is a usual way to read it.

Similarly, I would write `e^{-rt}` or $e^{-rt}$ to avoid any confusion. "$e$ to the power of negative $rt$" is reasonable.

Comment: Yes.  For beginners, or non-experts, include the word "power" in there.  As a short-cut, leave it out.